# No route patterns are currently defined for this Content Type

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using the Orchard cms tutorial http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-4

I have completed half way down the page until the

```
<Placement>
<Place Parts_Product_Edit="Content:1" />
</Placement>
```

When I run the application and click 'book'...the 'Sku' or 'Price' does not appear as it should (on the form) and a message appears at the top of the page...

```
No route patterns are currently defined for this Content Type. If you don't set one in the settings, a default one will be used.
```

I have tried google but cant find anything relevant

Would anyone have any ideas as how to resolve this? thank you

Comment: Well this is just warning you that you haven't specified a custom path for your content. I'm not sure this has anything to do with why your price and things are not appearing. To resolve the warning go into content types -> product -> expand autoroute and create a path. And when you say "on the form", I guess you mean in the admin section?

Answer (score 0):

Orchard 1.6...  Did a clean install and was going through an example and came across this error too.  I "Resolved" this by removing and re-adding back in AutoRoute.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but I resolved this by adding a "Title" part to my content type.